# HttpWebRequest WebException ProtocolError

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httprequest

I'm trying to understand something about exception handling with a `HttpWebRequest`.

I have a client library and it's making a request to a WebAPI controller;

```
HttpWebRequest r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

r.Method = "POST";
r.ContentType = "application/json";

foreach (var header in request.Headers)
{
     r.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value.ToString());
}

r.ContentLength = request.RequestBody.Length;

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(r.GetRequestStream()))
    writer.Write(request.RequestBody);
```

I know the request will throw an exception, and contain the message `entity already exists - 1234`.

When I get the response;

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)r.GetResponse())
{
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            return reader.ReadToEnd();

     return "Invalid"; 
 }
```

I get a `WebException` thrown. So, the caller of the request has a `try..catch` in it. And I get the `WebException`. What I get is a protocol error, not the `500 internal server error` that was thrown (using correct status codes to represent the message comes later). Now if I read the `Response` of the `WebException`, it does contain my message and the stacktrace.

**Questions**

- Why do I not get a status code of `500` in my response, why does it throw a protocol error?
- Is there a more correct way of handling the request?

I have searched around and found some people getting this issue when not using the correct headers etc. But as far as I can tell, I have added all the headers that I can and still get the same behavior.

Comment: 500 is an error code as specified in the *HTTP protocol*; the exception means "The protocol I'm using signalled an error". The 500 itself will be in the webexception response statuscode property.

Comment: So, is handling this by pulling the webexception response the right way to handle this? Or is it a mistake in the way I'm returning the exception? I'm not used to having to process exceptions like this, I'm normally able to handle the statuscode and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

An `500 internal server error` usually means that **the API received the request but threw an unhandled exception while processing it**, thus the "Internal Server Error".

You may log to a database or file all your API's unhandled exceptions to help your debugging process. Good luck.

Comment: Why the downvote? In 5 years it's the only answer the OP got